# Anaerobic Respiration vs Aerobic Respiration during physical activity

Tags: respiration

So I was wondering about the difference between aerobic and anaerobic respiration on the context of burning calories. While swimming we can choose to keep our head up and breathe, or keep our head below water for a stretch. Which will burn more calories for that time and why? And does anaerobic respiration cause fatigue of the brain due to insufficient oxygen?

Comment: Anaerobic respiration releases much less energy than aerobic respiration. Anaerobic respiration leads to a buildup of lactic acid in muscle tissue, which can feel like fatigue. Swimming is an aerobic exercise whether you head is at the stage of being under or over water. Exercises that count as anaerobic are those that require a lot of energy being produced by the cells in a short time (like sprinting).

Comment: @P.SN yeah but ultimately it is incomplete breakdown of glucose due to less oxygen availability... Shouldn't it affect the brain also?